# Can't enlarge photos in google images Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, google

Until yesterday, I was able to tap on a picture on google images to view the picture in large.
For example when you search "Apple" on google images you get many photos of it, and if you want to view one of them in large you just simply tap it.

But the problem is that since yesterday I suddenly can't do this! When I search anything on google images and get a lot of photos of it and then want to view it larger, it won't open. If I want to view the photo in large I have to do a hard long press and then it'll open. 
How to fix it?

*i tried looking up photos on different Search Engine (Yahoo) and there It's all working good and I can view the image in large when i tap on it but I don't want use it, I wanna use Google..

My iOS is 10.0 and my Safari version is Safari 10[image]

Comment: i'm having same problem.  Even if image is listed as 1200x1200 I get a small image of 225x225 or less.

Comment: Can you provide us with the version of macOS you're on, and the version for Safari?
I just checked on Safari Version 12.1.2 (14607.3.9) on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and it works fine.
Can you also post a screenshot?

Comment: My iOS is 10.0 and my Safari version is Safari 10.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, and my guess is that this is either a bug on Google's part or a compatibility issue. It's not only happening on the Safari app, but the Google app as well. My iOS version is 10.3.3, similar to how yours is 10.0 so it's very likely that it's a compatibility issue. Of course I hope it's only a bug that Google could easily fix but I doubt that's the case. I only made this account here because I was about to ask the same question...